# IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered

Tags: android, receiver, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to display banner ads..on the first screen as well as on the second screen...  when i try to go back to first screen through intent i am getting below error:

```
11-03 12:01:16.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1971): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.sec.android.ad.ScreenBroadcastReceiver@44f5aff8
11-03 12:01:16.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.forgetReceiverDispatcher(ActivityThread.java:793)
11-03 12:01:16.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:814)
11-03 12:01:16.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
11-03 12:01:16.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at com.sec.android.ad.AdHubView.onDetachedFromWindow(AdHubView.java:981)
11-03 12:01:16.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:6033)
11-03 12:01:16.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1158)
11-03 12:01:16.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1630)
11-03 12:01:16.464: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1971):     at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2671)
```

Comment: Apparently the BroadcastReceiver has not been registered in the system, so the system can not find it and thows this exception. From your description, I guess you register the BroadcastReceiver through code instead of AndroidManifest.xml, so within the life cycle of screen 1 and screen 2, you may not register and unregister it properly. Just my guess, you'd better post some code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have some problems in your view. If you look into your stacktrace, there is some view which is causing problem and hence your app is crashing and so receiver is registered. Also check if its registered in manifest or in your activity